# How do i make input text have to have at least 3 letters and if they have any less show a erro message. As2

Tags: windows, flash

ok so am trying to make a game and right now i can make it so if they enter nothing it shows a error but the problem with that is you can still just put one letter and i need them to have at least 3 letters in the input text field any less and my error_txt will say ("error you must enter at least 3 letters") please help i cant find this any ware else any help would be greatly appreciated!

ok my code on my button is:

```
on (release) {
if (texter_txt.length == 0)
{
    error_txt.text = ("please enter a name.");

}
else
{

    _root.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

}

Comment: exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701270/how-do-i-make-input-text-have-to-have-at-least-3-letters-and-if-they-have-any-le

Comment: And by the same user too. I suggest you delete one of the questions.

Comment: You know what this looks like? An attempt by someone to fatten an account by creating two.

Comment: i did not mean to post twice.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work? :

```
on (release) {

if (texter_txt.length < 3)
{

 error_txt.text = ("please enter a name.");

}

else
{

    _root.gotoAndStop(2);
}

}
```

Comment: 2 corrections: (1) It's W-O-U-L-D-N-'-T. Notice the apostrophe goes in place of the missing letter. (2) What's with the weird formatting? Read the [faq], check out how you're supposed to format answers.

Comment: no am not i only need help and i sorry i did not mean to post twice.

Answer (score 0):

on (release) {

if (texter_txt.length < 3)
{

error_txt.text = ("error you must enter at least 3 letters");

}

else
{

```
_root.gotoAndStop(2);
```

}

}